# Azure SQL Distinct Bug

Tags: azure, distinct

I am facing an issue with distinct function as below.

```
select person_id, count(*) as total
from persons
where person_id= '3ce59278-129c-45e2-8503-a6d813f63a1a-000000'
group by person_id

person_id |   total
3ce59278-129c-45e2-8503-a6d813f63a1a-000000 | 1
3ce59278-129c-45e2-8503-a6d813f63a1a-000000 | 1
3ce59278-129c-45e2-8503-a6d813f63a1a-000000 | 1
```

Person_id is primary key in the table.

Normally, it should return:

```
3ce59278-129c-45e2-8503-a6d813f63a1a-000000 | 3
```

Does anybody have faced this issue, and is there any workaround to fix it?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Are you _certain_ that the query you posted in fact generated this result?  I have never experienced anything like this, on any SQL database.

Comment: Yes, this is Azure Sql Server, and it seems to be a bug on distinct primary keys. But i wanted to know if anyone else have face this, and if there is any workaround in the querys to show the correct result.

Answer (score 1):

I found that if a Primary Key exists on the table SQL assumes uniqueness and doesn't physically do the DISTINCT; if the Primary Key is not enforced and duplicates exist they are returned by the DISTINCT query.

My soultion was to use a neutral function to prevent the assumption of uniqueness.

(Azure Synapse Analytics 2022).

E.g.:

```
CREATE TABLE KH_table
 ( col1 VARCHAR(1) NOT NULL
 ,  CONSTRAINT pk_KH_table PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED (col1) NOT ENFORCED
 )
;
INSERT
 INTO  KH_table
SELECT 'X' UNION ALL
SELECT 'X'
;
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM KH_table
;
SELECT DISTINCT RTRIM(col1) FROM KH_table
;
```